# Initiate for loop

Tags: loops, for-loop

I have the following question:

I am building a model when I first test for stationarity. Then I have an if loop, saying:

```
if p>0.05:
    x=y['boxcox']
else:
   x=y['Normal']
```

If the pvalue is bigger than 0.05, then I do the boxcox transformation, if not, then I use my original values. This works.

I then have a large code, that is working.
However, in the end, I want to transform my values back.
Again with the if loop.

But how do I get the if loop started?

I first wanted to do:

```
if any (x==y['BoxCox']):
   .....transform back
```

This works if I orginially have transformed my values, but not if I didn't, which makes sense, because the code does not know y['BoxCox'].
But how do I get the if loop initiated?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If (..) is usually a conditional statement, not a loop. Please add what language you are using and illustrate your problem with some code example.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I guess I meant a conditional statement. I am writing in Pyhton. I have done a transformation in a for loop at the beginning and would like to transform the data in the end back. But I dont know how to initiate that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you do not transform anything back, rather you remember the initial state. "Transforming back" sounds like a potential source of bugs. What if you alter your transformation algorithm and forget to update the transforming back part?

here is a simplified example, to illustrate my understanding of your problem:

```
x = 4

if x > 2:
   x = x + 1
else:
   x = x + 100 
print("Result = ", x)
print("Initial value was ???") // you cannot tell what was the initial x
```

You can simply do not touch the initial values, to be accessible at any time:

```
x = 4

if x > 2:
   result = x + 1
else:
   result = x + 100 

print("Result = ", result)
print("Initial value = , x)
```